# IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN Notification

Tags: c++, driver, system-shutdown

I created a driver that allocates data in memory, I need to save the data on the hard disk before the system shuts down. Researched enough, already tried several times to make the callback work, but the system is closed and notification is not performed.

*When querying the service with "SC", returns the flag IGNORES_SHUTDOWN.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

According to the ninth paragraph of the microsoft site, **all control handlers that have called SetServiceStatus with the SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN control code receive the SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN control code.**

How do I call SetServiceStatus with the SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN? I searched the internet and can not find how to modify the status of the service.

Any tips? Below is an excerpt of the code I'm using

```
DRIVER_DISPATCH DispatchShutdown;
NTSTATUS DispatchShutdown(__in struct _DEVICE_OBJECT  *DeviceObject, __in struct _IRP  *Irp)
{
    return 0;
}
...
DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN] = DispatchShutdown;
...
DeviceObject->Flags |= DO_BUFFERED_IO;

//status = IoRegisterLastChanceShutdownNotification(DeviceObject);
status = IoRegisterShutdownNotification(DeviceObject);
```

Comment: There are two different things here: getting system shutdown notifications, and making your driver stoppable. They are independent concepts: your driver does not need to be stoppable to receive shutdown notifications, and vice-versa. You can make your driver stoppable by setting a `DriverUnload` routine when you register your device (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this should not be the reason why your shutdown notification isn't working.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `IoRegisterShutdownNotification` and is it succeeding?

Comment: the function returns successfully yes! Simply sets the deviceobject as a parameter, does not have much to do.

I have the impression that the driver is being "closed, disabled" before receiving the notification. The main issue we have to clarify is: To receive notification IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN, simply set the callback and call the function IoRegisterShutdownNotification? Is there anything else to be done for that notification occur?

Comment: At the site below, someone reported that it is necessary to set the flag SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN see:http://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32.narkive.com/JSz2WfKp/windows-services-configuration

Comment: My mistake, I was confusing "stoppable" with ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN.

Comment: After many tests, I concluded that the call was being executed, but the FLT and ZW functions used in the event is that they were not working.